# Implement tileserver-gl in NW.js desktop program?

Tags: mapbox, node-webkit, tileserver-gl

Is there any way to make tileserver-gl working inside a desktop program so when the program start the tile server start with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can set up NW.js to run a local webserver, and point to that for your app. Here is an example:

- https://github.com/nwutils/nw-local-server-example

More examples for NW.js are at

- https://nwutils.io/#codeexamples